# Adding Localhost to recaptcha whitelist

Tags: html, recaptcha

How to add your localhost website to google recaptcha domain list. My domain name is localhost:8888/folder/index.php

When adding the above domain name you get "URL starts with an invalid scheme" error.

Comment: Scheme usually refers to http or https - also the domain name would be localhost not the entire path. I haven't really used reCaptcha for quite a while but those are a couple of possible issues that I can see just from your question. Perhaps try whitelisting something like `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8888` (change to https if you're serving the pages over HTTPS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get at least a free DNS and point it to your localhost. Google does not allow non domain names to be used.

What you can attempt to do is create an api key for another valid name and see if it works. They have been tightening down on api keys and I have seen a lot of keys no longer work that were used across more than one ip/domain.

All sub directories are not valid. Once you have a domain name pointing to the subdirectory then by default it will work across all sub directories of that domain name. Same applies to SSL.

> I'm getting an error "Localhost is not in the list of supported
> domains". This was working before, what should I do?
>
> localhost domains are no longer supported by default. If you wish to
> continue supporting them for development you can add them to the list
> of supported domains for your site key. Go to the admin console to
> update your list of supported domains. We advise to use a separate key
> for development and production and to not allow localhost on your
> production site key.
>
> 1: Create a separate key for your development
> environment
>
> 2: Add 127.0.0.1 to the list of allowed domains
>
> 3: Save changes and allow up to 30 mins for changes to take affect

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I think I understand the issue. So the 127.0.0.1 does not work for mine due to my DNS. So I could host the site for dev then finish testing there before having the domain name point to the site.  Are there any sites that allow for free hosting for development?

Comment: You are welcome. I actually do dev work on my home machine. What I do is get a free dns and point to my ip address. Add the free dns name to my api key and or use the real purchased domain name and add 127.0.0.1 to allowed domains.... or just flat out and point the real purchased domain name to my local machine and that way no info has to be re-inputted after a move to a remote location. I do all that using the A record and pointing it to my ip address.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for that insight. Just getting started in the dev world so every bit of advice helps!

Comment: @ZackTarr My pleasure if you have any questions please feel free to ping by using @ and my user name. This will auto message that a comment was directed to me. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

**To add the localhost to reCAPTCHA domain list you have to be careful in following steps:**

1. Remove http:// or https:// from the url.
2. Also remove the www. from url.
3. Do not add port number (e.g. localhost:8000)
4. You can just add **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**
5. if you want to add your site (e.g. http://www.example.com) then just add **example.com**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to get Recaptcha (especially invisible Recaptcha) working when they have javascript disabled except for specific whitelisted sites: this actually worked for me. Just add `[*.]localhost` to the javascript whitelist.